# Getting Aero to work with Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: aero

According to my recently-installed (today) Windows 7, my graphics card (GeForce GTS 250) could support Aero with drivers that support Aero. According to NVidia, I have the latest drivers (I upgraded today); I also have DirectX 10 (upgraded ten minutes ago).

At this point, I'm lost; I've nothing to upgrade, yet transparency is not working.

So, what do you need to know to help me get Aero working?

Comment: Post installing the drivers, did you try setting an Aero theme again? Right Click Desktop > Personalize > Windows 7? Just checking..

Comment: Yep, I currently have it set for Canada. Cause I'm Canadian. *ba-dum-thud*

Comment: It's looking like Windows 7 really doesn't like the thumb drive I'm using, to the point of even having trouble starting up. Which is strange, as it's just a data drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the `Control Panel -> System` then re-run the Windows Experience Index. It needs to determine that your card is capable of running Aero before it will enable.

After that, right-click on the Desktop and go to Personalize and select one of the Aero themes. If you cannot enable it, check at the bottom of that theme screen for a troubleshooting link on why Aero won't enable.

Some mirror drivers (like for remove connection software like VNC) can cause that issue and can other applications that don't like composition. These are rare, however.

Comment: It reported that it couldn't test my computer's video playback. No reason why.

Comment: Yep, I have the same problem, can't run windows experience, it always fails on video playback test. Since I can't run WE, can't turn on Aero neither. Is there a way to just force it on?

Answer (score 0):

Well if your Windows do have a clean install, then run a check online for Aero drivers. I encountered that every thing was working fine but my Aero settings were not working. I read alot checked all the things nothing worked.

Finally I used [Uxtheme Patch](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/UxTheme-Patch-for-Windows-7.shtml) it restored some errors and Aero settings were up again.I suggest you trouble shoot and post more details. The last resort i've already mentioned is patching using Uxtheme.
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Troubleshoot-problems-with-Windows-Aero
http://support.microsoft.com/mats/aero_effects_not_working/en-us